# What anthem does the West Indies cricket team use?

Tags: history, trivia

Every country has a national anthem of its own, and usually, it is played before the start of any world event, no matter what the sport is. But what is done for the West Indies cricket team? To my knowledge, it comprises players from a group of countries in the Caribbean Sea. Can anyone tell me what song gets played for them, and why?

Comment: I certainly don't know enough about this to give you a expert answer, but the song (and some info about their flag) is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Indies_cricket_team#Flag_and_anthem).

Answer (score 4):

West Indies, being a confederation of Carribean nations, obviously do not have a single national anthem. The West Indies Cricket Board (WICB) has instead adopted David Rudder's 'Rally Round the West Indies' as their anthem.

David Rudder is one of the most successful Calypso artists in the region. His song 'Rally 'Round the West Indies' captures the feel and emotions of the region and hence seemed to be a good enough pick for the WICB.